# Is there a way to grab the date and time out of a editText

Tags: android, datetime

I have two editText one for date and one for time. Is there a way to get the info from both so I can use the code below and store the correct date and time?

```
    newTime.year = dateAndTime.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    newTime.month = dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    newTime.monthDay = dateAndTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    newTime.hour = dateAndTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    newTime.minute = dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);


    enteredTime = (int) ((newTime).toMillis(true) / 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a really bad idea to use EditText fields for date and time. There are specific View controls you can use to provide a much better interface for users:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-timepicker.html

Comment: The problem I am having is that if the user enters the date and time it works.  However, if the user does not enter date and time, the current time is stored in my db, when I want the info the db populated the editText with.  Any ideas of how to do this?